# TextMate PEP8 bundle: how do I enable it?

Tags: python, textmate, pep8, textmatebundles

I want to validate my Python code against PEP8, so I've installed the PEP8 TextMate bundle: https://github.com/ppierre/python-pep8-tmbundle

I've followed the README to install it:

```
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/TextMate/Bundles/
git clone git://github.com/ppierre/python-pep8-tmbundle.git "Python PEP8.tmbundle"
osascript -e 'tell app "TextMate" to reload bundles'
```

Then I restarted TextMate. But looking at my Python script, still no PEP8 errors are being highlighted, even when I add them.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but what do I do to enable it?

Comment: As an alternative, have you heard of pylint?

Comment: Pylint would be good also, as long as it is PEP8-compliant.. .

Comment: Are you using Textmate 1 or 2?

Comment: Pylint is the standard tool for checking for PEP8 errors (and others) in Python source code. I think there is probably a TextMate bundle, or you could run it seperately.